# C# Syntax Error into insert statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        Dim strSQL As String

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBLLOGIN (USERNAME,[PASSWORD],DISPLAYNAME,ROLEID,SECRETQUESTION,SECRETANSWER,ISACTIVE,STUDENTNUMBER, APPLICANTID,EMAILADDRESS) "
        strSQL += "values( '" & Me.txtUName.Text & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & Me.txtPassword.Text & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & txtFirstName.Text & " " & txtMiddleName.Text & " " & txtLastName.Text & "' "

        strSQL += ",'" & 6 & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & Me.ddlsecretquestion.SelectedValue & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & Me.txtSecretAnswer.Text & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & "NO" & "' "
        strSQL += ",'" & studNumber & "' "
        strSQL += "," & studNumber.Replace("SY15000", "") & " "
        strSQL += ",'" & Me.txtUName.Text & "') "

        Dim cmdQuery As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, AccessConnectionString)
        Dim xgen As Integer
        cmdQuery.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text

        xgen = cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuerystrong text
```

i dont get why i get error into insert statement, ive checked the reserve words and as far as i can see password is the only reserve word in there. my guess is the student number since its a string and im changing the value. but still im not sure. ive tried a couple of solution by using session(studentnumber) but still no go.

Comment: What is the final `strSQL` just before execute it? What are your column types? What is the _exact_ error message? And more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: First step - print out the complete string and see what it looks like - check for errors there. Also, start reading up on parameters, which are a far safer, and eventually *simpler* way of passing data across without having to turn it all into strings (and then having to deal with formatting issues)

Comment: First, what's the error message you got? second, try not to use string concatenation to insert SQL, try converting to parameterized SQL Queries

Comment: "*why i get error*" - it will be much more easy to answer your question if you'll provide the text of error you're getting.

Comment: Without knowing the error message, the values you are using or possibly seeing the final SQL statement, this is very hard to answer.

Comment: Get the error from the catch and display it.

Comment: Post the error and the sql string needed here

Answer (score 0):

Following this [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) use parametrized query as in this method:

```
Public Sub CreateMyOleDbCommand(connection As OleDbConnection, _
   queryString As String, parameters() As OleDbParameter)

    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)
    command.CommandText = _
       "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE Country = ? AND City = ?"
    command.Parameters.Add(parameters)

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To command.Parameters.Count - 1
       command.Parameters.Add(parameters(j))
    Next j

    Dim message As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To command.Parameters.Count - 1
        message += command.Parameters(i).ToString() + ControlChars.Cr
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine(message)
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This is a best practice. Should help to solve the issue. I assume you can try using this method. Upvote.

Comment: Exactly. Look at code where query is concatenation of strings - this is mess. How do you want to find issue? Rewrite using parameters and maybe quicker find error. Upvote for Igor.

Answer (score 0):

```
strSQL += "," & studNumber.Replace("SY15000", "") & " "
```

should be

```
strSQL += ",'" & studNumber.Replace("SY15000", "") & "' "
```

You are missing quotes since it is a string like STUDENTNUMBER.

Comment: I think we need to fill a number(by replacing text). Thank you to try.

Comment: So in this case you need to do some conversion, isn't it?

Comment: No, because sql server instructions is string based. Really need many validations to make this safe. But i think the issue isnt here.

Comment: So if it is string, you need the quotes. Did you try what I posted?

Comment: The data type to this column isnt a varchar. I think is a numeric type.

Comment: Can you check and tell what is the type?